Layer-wise Student-Teacher Optimization for Lllama 3.2 1B
I'm trying to recreate an experiment from a paper I have read about a teacher-student layer-wise distillation.
I'm using the L2 norm to optimize every transformer layer independently.
However, it does not converge to a working model. Any ideas on why?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, LlamaConfig
from datasets import load_dataset
from lm_eval.models.huggingface import HFLM
from lm_eval import simple_evaluate

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Load original pre-trained model and tokenizer
# ------------------------------------------------------------
model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B"  # Replace with actual model name
teacher_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, attn_implementation="flash_attention_2")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Move to GPU if available
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
teacher_model.to(device).to(torch.bfloat16)
teacher_model.eval()

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 2. Create a second model with the same configuration but random initialization
# ------------------------------------------------------------
config = teacher_model.config
student_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config, attn_implementation="flash_attention_2")
student_model.to(device).to(torch.bfloat16)

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Copy weights from teacher_model except self_attn q, k, v
# ------------------------------------------------------------
with torch.no_grad():
    for (orig_name, orig_param), (rand_name, rand_param) in zip(teacher_model.named_parameters(), student_model.named_parameters()):
        if any(attn_name in orig_name for attn_name in ["q_proj", "k_proj", "v_proj"]):
            # Skip copying attention projection weights
            continue
        else:
            rand_param.data.copy_(orig_param.data)

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 4. Prepare dataset and dataloader
# ------------------------------------------------------------
streaming_dataset = load_dataset("HuggingFaceFW/fineweb", split="train", streaming=True)

def tokenize_streaming_data(example):
    return tokenizer(example["text"], truncation=True, padding="max_length", max_length=1024)

streaming_dataset = streaming_dataset.map(tokenize_streaming_data)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(streaming_dataset, batch_size=8)

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Define lm_eval function
# ------------------------------------------------------------
def lm_eval(student_model, tokenizer, device):

    results = simple_evaluate(
        model=HFLM(pretrained=student_model, tokenizer=tokenizer, backend="causal"),
        tasks=["arc_easy"],
        num_fewshot=0,
        device=device,
        log_samples=False,

    )

    print(f"Evaluation at step {step} - Results:")
    for alias, result in results["results"].items():
        acc = result["acc,none"]
        acc_norm = result["acc_norm,none"]
        print(f"{alias}: {acc} (normalized: {acc_norm})")

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Define loss function and optimizer
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# L2 loss between layer outputs 
criterion = lambda x, y: torch.norm(x - y, p=2, dim=(-1,)).mean()
optimizer = optim.AdamW(student_model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

student_model.train()
teacher_model.eval()

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# 7. Training loop with evaluation every 1000 steps
# ------------------------------------------------------------
step = 0
for batch in dataloader:
    step += 1
    input_ids = torch.stack(batch["input_ids"]).to(device).t()  # shape [seq_len, batch]
    attention_mask = torch.stack(batch["attention_mask"]).to(device).t()

    seq_len = input_ids.size(1)  # number of tokens per sequence
    position_ids = torch.arange(seq_len, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
    position_ids = position_ids.unsqueeze(0).expand(input_ids.size(0), seq_len)  # [batch_size, seq_len]

    kwargs = {"attention_mask": attention_mask, "position_ids": position_ids}

    # Get teacher outputs
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = teacher_model(input_ids, output_hidden_states=True, **kwargs)
        output = output["hidden_states"]

    # Run random model layers, using teacher outputs as inputs
    loss = 0.0
    # for i, layer in enumerate(student_model.model.layers):
    #     loss += criterion(layer(output[i], **kwargs)[0], output[i+1])
    for i, (student_layer, teacher_layer) in enumerate(zip(student_model.model.layers, teacher_model.model.layers)):
        loss += criterion(student_layer.self_attn(output[i], **kwargs)[0], 
                          teacher_layer.self_attn(output[i], **kwargs)[0])
    loss /= len(student_model.model.layers)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if step % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Step {step} - Loss: {loss.item()}")

    # Every 1000 steps, evaluate
    if step % 1000 == 0:
        student_model.eval()
        lm_eval(student_model, tokenizer, device)
        student_model.train()

I have tried to ablate optimizer hyper-parameters (weight decay, learning rate), have different initializations for the self-attention weights, with and without normalization of the last layer.
